# mayavi misaligned streamline and image plane when overplotted

Tags: python, graphics, mayavi

I have 3D scalar and vector data that I'm plotting together with streamlines (`mlab.pipeline.streamline`) and image planes (`mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget`).  This is often working, but sporadically (i.e. on some data sets) the two types of graphics become misaligned - even though the data shapes are all exactly the same.

**Good example**:

[image]

**Bad example**:

[image]

And this is always the paradigm: the bounding box of the streamlines becomes stretches along a single axis... no settings are changing!

For example, I have a scalar field `scal` with the same dimensions as a vector field `vect`:

```
mlab.options.offscreen = True

# Initialized figure                                                                                                                                                             
fig   = mlab.figure(size=[1000,1000])                                                            
extent     = [0,1,0,1,0,1]

shape = np.shape(scal)
x,y,z      = np.mgrid[ 0:1.0:1j*shape[0] , 0:1.0:1j*shape[1] , 0:1.0:1j*shape[2] ]

# Draw vector field                                                                                                                                                              
u,v,w      = vect[...,0], vect[...,1], vect[...,2]
vect_field = mlab.pipeline.vector_field(x,y,z, u,v,w)

streams = mlab.pipeline.streamline(vect_field, figure=fig, extent=extent, reset_zoom=False, \
                                     seedtype='plane', seed_scale=2.0, colormap='Greens')

streams.stream_tracer.integration_direction = 'both'
mlab.outline()
seed = streams.seed.widget
seed.set( normal=[0.0,0.0,1.0] )
seed.set( center=[0.5,0.5,0.5] )                                          
seed.set( resolution=SEED_RESOLUTION )
seed.enabled = False                            

# Draw scalar field
scal       = np.log10(scal)                                                                 
scal_field = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(x,y,z, scal)                                        
midz       = np.int(np.floor(shape[2]*0.5))                                                 
plane1 = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(scal_field, figure=fig, plane_orientation='z_axes', \
                                         slice_index=midz, opacity=0.1, transparent=True, \
                                         extent=extent, reset_zoom=False )
plane2 = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(scal_field, figure=fig, plane_orientation='x_axes', \
                                         slice_index=0, opacity=0.1, \
                                         extent=extent, reset_zoom=False )


mlab.text3d(0.5,0.5,1.07, 'Time = %04.0f' % time, scale=0.05, figure=fig)
mlab.colorbar()
mlab.view(35, 75, 3.0, focalpoint=[0.5,0.5,0.4])
```

---

Code with data to reproduce the problem can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4FXIXq2e3y4UGMyREFaWnV2Mjg&usp=sharing

Comment: can you give a fully working example ?

Comment: @SAAD I've just posted data and code to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `image_plane_widget` doesn't accept an 'extent' argument at all.  Removing the 'extent' argument from both `image_plane_widget` and `streamline` made the objects match up.